# Get contact image displayed in incoming phone calls on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, contacts

I am inserting a new contact with Apple's Contacts framework. The image is a .png from Asset catalog. After the successful insertion the new contact is visible with the correct image in the Contacts app. However, when there is an incoming call from the newly inserted contact the image is NOT displayed.

I couldn't find any reliable information about the exact cases when does the iOS display the contact image. Is it true that images will only appear if the user sets it manually? Did I miss something? Could you please point me to a good documentation or provide me an explanation?  (The only relevant information is in this article: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202158 but I fulfill every requirement and it is probably not closely related.)

Code for the contact insertion:

```
let newContact = CNMutableContact()  
...  
if let image = UIImage(named: "ContactImage") {  
  newContact.imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)  
}  
...  
let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()  
saveRequest.addContact(newContact, toContainerWithIdentifier: nil)  

do {  
  try contactStore.executeSaveRequest(saveRequest)  
  log.debug("New contact successfully saved!")  
} catch let error as NSError {  
  log.error(error.localizedDescription)  
} catch {  
  log.error("Unknown error happened during contact saving.")  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted Apple Developer Technical Support and their engineers determined that this would be best handled as a bug report. The submitted bug's ID is *26033574*.

**UPDATE**

Apple asked me the following question.

> Can you please share the vcard and image you’re using on the contact card?

I shared the *vCard* with them and unfortunately there was no image in it, although on iOS (and macOS) the image was clearly visible.

Comment: Any followup from apple?

Answer (score 0):

I found that saving the contact two times in a row solved the problem.

1. Save the contact
2. Add the image to the contact
3. Resave the contact